# MySQL date greater than returns all rows

Tags: mysql, sql

`showdate` is a datetime field - the following sql returns all rows, not only the ones with dates later than 2016-08-31.

```
SELECT * FROM  shows WHERE  showdate >  '2016-08-31'
```

I did a workaround by creating a unixdate field, and making the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  shows WHERE  udate >1472626800
```

However, from what I read, the former should work, and I am curious as to why it doesn't.

Comment: Please add a table structure and possible a few rows of example data.

Comment: In another comment, you show a different SQL query with additional boolean terms. When you ask a question about code, **post the code you are having trouble with**, not some other code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM shows where udate > 1472626800 AND showstate = 'MO' OR showstate = 'KS'
```

Keep in mind rules of precedence in boolean expressions.

```
X AND Y OR Z
```

This is the same as:

```
(X AND Y) OR Z
```

Which is true anywhere Z is true, even if X and Y are false.

To fix this, add parentheses explicitly to override the default boolean operation precedence:

```
X AND (Y OR Z)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be you should convert your string properly in date

```
 SELECT * FROM  shows WHERE  showdate > str_to_date( '2016-08-31', '%Y-%m-%d');
```

or with your last comment

```
 SELECT * FROM  shows 
 WHERE  showdate > str_to_date( '2016-08-31', '%Y-%m-%d') 
 AND showstate IN ('MO','KS') order by showdate ASC
```

Comment: I must be using the wrong sql for my filters, because when I do it like this, the date filter fails:

    SELECT * FROM shows where udate > 1472626800  AND showstate =  'MO' OR  showstate =  'KS'

Comment: show a sample please and tell me the data type of showdate

Comment: OK, it was a total dumb, stupid noob mistake. This sql does what I wanted: SELECT * FROM shows where udate > 1472626800  AND  showstate IN ('MO','KS') order by udate ASC

Comment: Perhaps an admin will delete this question. The AND operator was including the rows with earlier dates, of course.